# ¿Cómo puedo remover las cantidades a la derecha de las barras de un gráfico de importancia hecho con SHAP en Python?

Tags: plot

tengo un plot de importancia de variables tipo "gain" hecho con SHAP y quisiera remover las cantidades que aparecen a la derecha de las barras, pero no sé cómo hacerlo. Alguna recomendación? gracias :)
[image: Gráfico "Feature importance"]